# Examples of comparison-based algorithms that are not a sort or a search over lists

Tags: algorithms, sorting, search-algorithms, comparison

**Can you share examples of comparison-based algorithms used in practice that are not a sort or a search over lists?** *Heapify* is an example of a comparison-based algorithm that is neither a sort nor a search. Heapify is of course part of Heapsort and still operates over lists. Are there other examples of comparison-based algorithms that are not sorts or searches over lists and are used in a different context than sorting or searching or operate over different data structures?

**By comparison-based I mean the standard definition:** every basic operation (swaps, assignments, ...) need to be carried out on the basis of a series of comparisons only. This includes the transitive closures of the outcomes of comparisons (as in quicksort: a swap can be carried out on elements a and b when a > p and p > b has been determined, where p is the pivot. In this case no direct comparison between a and b was made, but their order is deduced based on the transitive closure of the relations). The elements to be ordered need to satisfy a linear order (total order), i.e. a <= b or a >= b always needs to hold (as for the case of integers, real numbers, words (lexicographical order) etc.) Put another way: these are algorithms for which the computation can be modelled via a decision tree. Their execution is the same on data that share the same relative order. In the case of lists: the execution is the same on the reverse ordered list [4,3,1] as on the reverse ordered list [50,6,5].

**I prefer examples for which the comparison-time (worst-case or average-case) has been determined, but I'm open to others examples for which this has not been done.**

It seems that the *Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm* and *Booth's Algorithm* may fall into this category, i.e. *string matching algorithms*.

Pseudonym suggested *priority scheduling* below (I did not check this sufficiently yet but it seems a possible fit). Any others?

Comment: This is going to depend what you mean by "comparison-based". In general, you typically use comparison when you need an ordering, and beyond fundamental data structures like priority queues, it's probably going to matter what you are ordering. For example, there is a whole class of algorithms based around scheduling which involve a notion of priority.

Comment: @Pseudonym I updated it with a description of the type of algorithm I have in mind.

Comment: There are some examples in computational geometry, for example [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I summarise some comparison-based algorithms found thanks to suggestions here and also in relation to examples I know of or found online. The Huffman algorithm may raise some eyebrows, but it seems to have all the hallmarks of a comparison-based algorithm. Do add any if you know of more examples (or share criticism on the ones listed below if you deem them not to fit). I find the usual presentation of comparison-based computation a little short on examples, so aim to use this list to show their impact beyond sorts and searches. I did not add priority scheduling yet but may add it later pending a closer look at how it goes beyond sorting.

**Min-max heap construction.** Min-max heaps combine a min-heap and a max-heap. The data structure provides constant time retrieval and logarithmic time removal of both the minimum and maximum elements. It forms a useful data structure to implement a double-ended priority queue.

**Beap construction.** A  compromise between costs of searching and updating
is to create a structure with the same father-son relationship as a heap, and with most nodes having two sons. The difference is that in general each node will have two parents--a beap.

**String matching.** A string-matching algorithm finds the starting index $m$ in string $s$ that
matches the search word $w$. The Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

**Lexicographically minimal string rotation** Aka least circular substring is the problem of finding the rotation of a string possessing the lowest lexicographical order of all such rotations.

**Prefix order construction.** The Huffman file encoding algorithm. Huffman code is an optimal prefix code used for lossless data compression.

**Balanced k-d-trees construction.** Useful for searches involving a multidimensional search key (e.g. range searches and nearest neighbour searches) and creating point clouds.